# which backend language store image upload b user?and how it's work?

Tags: sql, database, image, backend

how to save a user uploaded images from a website in computers and what are the basic backend language which work to save the uploaded image.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend Node.js. You tagged c++ but that language is only needed if you really need massive computations in your backend (and even then, the main frame of the backend rarely is written in c++).